# Using SVM-struct multiclass classification in C++

Tags: c++, svm

I just downloaded SVM-struct multiclass source files from http://svmlight.joachims.org/svm_struct.html, and I'd like to do classification through calling some function from my C++ program.

I couldn't find a documentation about this. Is there some functions that I can call to do classification in C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded source files, you can include them into your project, then include them into the source files where you want to use them and then call the functions. If dlls were provided, you need
to use them.
If you are searching for other libraries for classification, I can suggest you the following:

- SVMLib
- boost libraries (boost has some libraries for classification)

Comment: LibSVM? I am not aware of SVMLib library.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "Shark machine learning library" for C++. The library supports SVM with different Kernel functions, NNet and a few other types of classifiers.

http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/index.html

You may also use LIBSVM:

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/‎

Both of these libraries are still being maintained.